# flutter - add Widget attribute only if condition is met

Tags: flutter

I want to add widget attribute only if condition is met - I want the 'left' attribute to appear only if the index i is bigger than 0. How can I do this?

```
 for(int i = 0; i < attendingImagesList.length; i++) {
          avatars.add(
            Positioned(
              left: ((avatarWidth - overlayWidth)*i).toDouble(),
              child:  CircleAvatar(
                radius: 14,
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(this.attendingImagesList[i])
              )
          ));
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a ternary and if it's zero make it null.

```
for(int i = 0; i < attendingImagesList.length; i++) {
          avatars.add(
            Positioned(
              left: i == 0 ? null : ((avatarWidth - overlayWidth)*i).toDouble(),
              child:  CircleAvatar(
                radius: 14,
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(this.attendingImagesList[i])
              )
          ));
        }
```